# ActiveAdmin concern refactoring

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring, activeadmin

I've made concern for duplicate parts in ActiveAdmin for simle models. It works, but code looks little bit ugly.
May you look at it and help me with refactoring?

In case of differences of starting time I used class ActiveAdmin controller variable, instead of instance. I did not found any pretty methods for this feature. May be you know it?

```
module ActiveAdminSimpleMenu

def simple_menu_for(klass, options = {})
  ActiveAdmin.register klass do
    permit_params(*(klass.main_fields + (options[:permitted_params] || [])))
    controller.class_variable_set(:@@permitted_params, options[:permitted_params])
    controller.class_variable_set(:@@klass, klass)

    controller do
      def scoped_collection
        permitted_params = self.class.class_variable_get :@@permitted_params
        self.class.class_variable_get( :@@klass).includes(*(permitted_params.map(&:cut_id)))
      end
    end if options[:permitted_params]

    index_for_main_fields klass
    filter_for_main_fields klass
    form_for_main_fields klass
  end
end
```

Comment: If your code works and you want to refactor it, then consider moving the question to [codereview.se].